# How to make effective index for search

Tags: mysql, sql, database, doctrine-orm

How to make the index on Table for speeding up searching.

I have two tables like these

(I created tables with doctorine from symfony2, but in fetching use plain mysql from python script.)

Now I want to exec this sql many times(changing x value)

`select recordDate,closePrice from PriceDay where company_price=x ORDER BY recordDate DESC`

So I wan to set the index like `indexes={@ORM\Index(name="code_index",columns={"company_price","recordDate"})})` , but I am not sure it is the best solution or not. Pairs of company_price and recordDate are unique. Could you help some ideas??

```
 * @ORM\Table(indexes={@ORM\Index(name="code_index",columns={"company_price","recordDate"})})
```

PriceDay table

```
class PriceDay
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Company")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_price", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $closePrice = 0;

     /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */

    private $recordDate;
```

Company Table

```
class Company
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


   /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
        /**
     * @var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(name="enabled",type="boolean")
     */
    private $enabled = true;
```

Comment: Your suggested index is fine.

Comment: Thank you , So, maybe I can't speed up any more.I have to exec this query 1000 times. I might better thinkg make less sql exec times

Comment: make less sql exec times = yes. please do that, your server will thank you